# Adding a string to a NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How do I add the string below into the newscount object

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewsStory1" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];


newscount = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString *content],@"XXX", @"12345", nil];
```

Comment: Is this about a UITextView?  There's no UITextView in your code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so simple:

```
newscount = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:content,@"XXX", @"12345", nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Simpler and autoreleased:

```
newscount = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:content,@"XXX", @"12345", nil];
```